# Two-way ANOVA doesn't detect differences between conditions in a specific group?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, t-test, experiment-design

OK, so let's say we have independent variables Condition (A or B) and Race (1 or 2 or 3). Then say we have a dependent variable X. We can run a two-way ANOVA to find out if there's an effect due to Condition alone (do people in A differ from people in B on variable X), Race alone (do people of race 1, 2 and 3 differ from each other on variable X), and interaction Condition*Race (does Condition and Race interact). However, let's say that the condition has a strong effect **only on race 3** (And this is something I am looking to detect). This will be obvious if I run a t-test for Condition A (Race 3) vs. Condition B (Race 3) on variable X. But the ANOVA isn't used to test for this, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, ANOVA will tell you there differences among group means but not which. To find out which you can use a t-test or a Tukey multiple comparison test. If you are doing this in R you can use TukeyHSD() function on the anova object and it will perform the MCP for you.

Comment: I would add that there is multiple a posteriori test that help you find differences among group. Tukey is very restrictive. There's also the LSmeans. But you can do those a posteriori test only on independent variables found significant in the ANOVA.